# EE and Channel Images Copy and Paste

Tags: ee2, channel-images

Has anyone noticed a problem when trying to add a CI description with copy and right click to paste into the description field? For me it is not being saved, if I paste it then re-type one letter or more it saves OK as does straight typing.

Using CI 5.4.19 and EE 2.10.1.

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Channel Images and you paste or write in a description field you have to click out of the field so it saves. The AJAX action is on the "blur" so if you click submit in EE the blur never occurs because how EE handles the submit.

Comment: Thanks, works fine if I left click first. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you pasting from my friend?

I've seen isues when you rtake your copy from like word documents ect (it copies nasty MS centric html formatting which can result in nothing the other end)...

A good test, copy your text, paste it into notepad, then re-copy and paste into CI tectfield. DOes that work?